# decommissioned beacon how to add to another project

Tags: android, beacon, estimote

I registry Estimote beacon, using Beacon Tools (app by google) and assign to one of my projects. Then I want to delete (in purpose to assign it to another project) this beacon from this project so I decommissioned it. Now I can't do anything with it ? what should I do to reset/delete it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only what you can do is change ID of this Estimote beacon. Log into Estimote app select your devices and change UUID/MINOR/MAJOR.
More: https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/200868188-How-to-modify-UUID-Major-and-Minor-values-